# How can I log out of facebook with out a api key or a FB application

Tags: javascript, facebook, coldfusion

Good day all,
Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a webpage (public) that I am trying to give the user the ability to simply share the page.  After the user shares the link they click on a link to close window.  In my close window function I also want to log them out of Facebook.  Is this even possible.  I have tried a variety of ways with out any success.

Thanks in advance,
Calvin Click

Comment: Do you want to log the user out even if they were logged into Facebook _before_ accessing your web page?  (that sounds plain wrong...)

Comment: People often use Facebook to increase their traffic and seo related stuff, but @Calvin click seems to use facebook to decrease his traffic. Is it dude?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to automatically log a user out of Facebook via the API. If the user wants to log out, they will, otherwise I don't even understand why your site would want them to log out.